# Compute $\int_{C_{R}}^{ }\left|f\left(z\right)\right|^2\text{d}z$ knowing Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I know that
$$
f\left(z\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{5}\frac{a_k}{z^k}
$$
Let $C_{R}$ ba the circe centered at the origin of radius $R$, how can i compute
$$
\int_{C_{R}}^{ }\left|f\left(z\right)\right|^2\text{d}z
$$
I know that the residu of $f$ at $0$ is $a_1$.

Comment: Write $z=Re^{i\theta}$ and exapand $|f(z)|^{2}$. Residue Theorem does not apply because $|f|^{2}$ is not analytic.

Answer (score 1):

Use that $\overline z = R^2 z^{-1}$ if $\lvert z \rvert = R$. Then for such $z$ $$\overline{f(z)} = \sum_{n=0}^5\frac{\overline{a_n} z^n}{R^{2n}}.$$ Now $\lvert f(z) \rvert^2 = f(z) \overline{f(z)}$. Write this as a rational function in $z$ on $C_R$ and you will find its residue is $$\sum_{n=0}^4\frac{\overline{a_n}a_{n+1}}{R^{2n}}.$$ So your integral is $2 \pi \mathrm i$ times that residue.